# MS Access database 'Locked' for users on Terminal Server

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010

We have an MS Access front-end application that connects with Access tables on a network share.  The application is installed on three terminal servers and several desktops.  It works fine on the desktops and two of the terminal servers.  On the third terminal server, we have the following problem.

If one user (no particular user) starts the application more than about 15 minutes prior to the others, the others all get the message "The database has been placed in a state by user 'Admin' that prevents it from being opened or locked".

If all users start the application within an approximate 15 minute window, they all work fine, until they close the application.  At this point, no one can get back in until the first person to have started the application closes it.  Once that person is out, everyone can get back in.

There are no obvious differences between the terminal servers.  We are using the Microsoft Access 2010 Runtime to run the application.  The setup is the same across all systems.

Comment: Have you been able to test this to see if this happens 100% of the time on multiple computers in a controlled test?

Comment: It only happens on this one terminal server.  It doesn't seem to matter which user logs in first.  5 users can log in, they all work.  As soon as someone logs off, they get the error.  The initial user (usually all users because no one knows who was first) logs off and everyone can get back in.